# Deriving the basis vectors of the Krylov subspace

Tags: conjugate-gradient

I am struggling to follow the derivation of the basis vectors of the Krylov subspace starting from [22:27](https://youtu.be/InhsIE6nMBI?t=1347) of this [video](https://youtu.be/InhsIE6nMBI?t=1347).

If the next step of a search is given as

$$
x^k = x^{k - 1} + \alpha_{k - 1} r^{k - 1}
$$

where $x^{k- 1}$ is the previous step, $r^{k- 1}$ is an orthogonal search direction and $\alpha_{k - 1}$ a constant. It follows that

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
b - A x^k & = b - A\left(x^{k - 1} + \alpha_{k - 1} r^{k - 1}\right) \\
          & = b - A \, x^{k - 1} - \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1} \\
          & = r^{k - 1} - \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1} 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

The second to the last equation is where it to fall apart for me (see [24:42](https://youtu.be/InhsIE6nMBI?t=1482)). The sign of the last term changes and the speaker writes

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
b - A x^k & = b - A x^{k - 1} + \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1} \\
          & = r^{k - 1} + \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1} 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

Subsequently the speaker uses the above equation as follows:

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^{k + 1} & = x^k + \alpha_k r^k \\
          & = x^k + \alpha_k \left(b - A x^k\right) \\
          & = x^k + \alpha_k \left(r^{k - 1} - \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1} \right) \\
          & = x^k + \alpha_k r^{k - 1} - \alpha_k \alpha_{k - 1} A \, r^{k - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

And from there makes the leap to write

$$
x^{k + 1} = x^0 + \alpha_1 r^0 + \alpha_2 A \, r^0 + \alpha_3 A^2 \, r^0 + \ldots + \alpha_{k - 1} A^k \, r^0
$$

Now I am lost completely.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some small mistakes in the video, but the final result can be obtained easily. One thing to mentioned is the fact that $\alpha_k$ in the final result are not the same $\alpha_k$ at the beginning.

We know that:

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= x_k + \alpha_{k} r_k\\
r_k &= b - Ax_k
\end{align}

Let prove that $$x_{k} = x_0 + \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \gamma^{k}_l A^l r_0$$

Using induction. For $k=0$ the result is trivial. Now since
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= x_k + \alpha_k r_k\\
&= x_k + \alpha_k \left(b - Ax_k\right)\\
&= x_k + \alpha_k \left(b - Ax_0 - A\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\gamma^k_l A^lr_0\right)\\
&= x_0 + \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \gamma^k_l A^lr_0 + \alpha_k \left(b  - Ax_0\right) - \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \alpha_k\gamma^k_l A^{l+1}r_0\\
&= x_0 + \sum_{l=0}^{k} \gamma^{k+1}_{l} A^{l}r_0
\end{align}

Where $\gamma^{k+1}_{0} = \alpha_k + \gamma^k_{0}$, $\gamma^{k+1}_{l} = \gamma^{k}_{l} - \alpha_k \gamma^{k}_l$ for $l=1,\ldots,k-1$ and $\gamma^{k}_{k+1} = -\alpha_k\gamma^{k-1}_{k}$